# Template class not inheriting base template class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am trying to create a template sub class that inherits a template base class, but I am getting a compile error when initializing the template sub class. I think it is because I am probably not defining the constructor for the sub class properly, but I am unsure as to the syntax to do it properly.

Here is the header file with both classes:

```
template<typename T> class Matrix
{
public:

~Matrix();
Matrix();
Matrix(uint rows, uint columns);
uint height;
uint width;
uint stride;
size_t size;

private:
vector<T> elements;
T* firstElement;

};

template<typename T> class NumMatrix : public Matrix<T>
{
public:

NumMatrix(uint rows, uint columns) : Matrix<int>::Matrix<T>(uint rows, uint columns)
{

}
};
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Matrix.h"

using namespace std;

void main()
{
NumMatrix<int> A(2,2);
}
```

The compile error is: 'NumMatrix::NumMatrix' : no overloaded functions takes 2 arguments

Comment: Note that the member `T* firstElement;`, if it's for what the name suggests that it's for, needs to update whenever an instance is copied, either by copy construction or by copy assignment. But you haven't declared a copy constructor or copy assignment operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
NumMatrix(uint rows, uint columns) : Matrix<int>::Matrix<int>(uint rows, uint columns)
```

to

```
NumMatrix(uint rows, uint columns) : Matrix<T>(rows, columns)
```

---

Also, to be standard-conforming (compiles with more compilers), change this:

```
void main()
```

to

```
int main()
```

Comment: Oops, typed that in wrong. The Matrix<int> should have been Matrix<T>. But I changed it to what you suggested and I get two compile errors that says unexpected end of file found and expected a '{' not ';', its referencing the changed line above because its expecting some declaration below it?

Comment: @user3390212: sorry I didn't delete enough. check it out now. (since this edit wasn't recorded in edit history, here's what i did: i now changed e.g. the original `uint rows` to just `rows` in the initializer expression)

Comment: Look carefully at what he told you to replace